# React Component Render function testing using Enzymes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have recently started testing React App and could not test React App properly. Please take a look at scenario below

**React Component**

```
class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            sheetNames:this.props.sheetNames?this.props.sheetNames:[],
            sheetColumnDimensions:this.props.sheetColumnDimensions?this.props.sheetColumnDimensions:{},
     }
 }

render(){
      let list=
         this.state.sheetNames.map((sheetName,index)=>
             <React.Fragment key={index}> 
                   {   
                       this.state.sheetColumnDimensions[sheetName].map((column,idx)=>
                           <option key={idx} value={column}>{column}</option>
                       )
                   }
             </React.Fragment>
      );
     return (
         <div>
             <div id="fieldForFiltering">
                  <select id="columnForFilter"onChange={(event)=>this.handleOnChange(event)} >
                          {list}
                   </select>
             </div>           
         </div>
       )
}

export default Filter
```

**React test script for the above component**

```
import React from 'react';
import FilterDetails from "../Components/Filters/FilterDetails";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';


enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


describe('FilterDetails component test suite', () => {
    let props ={
        sheetNames:["Stocks","Returns"],
        sheetColumnDimensions:{Stocks:["Sales","Profit"],Returns:["Status","Quantity"]}
    }
    let wrapper = shallow(<FilterDetails {...props}/>);
    
    it("should render initial layout of FilterDetails.jsx ", () => {
        expect(wrapper.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})
```

on testing the app as above I could not see the list `<options value={column}>{column}</option>` in the snapshot, it only renders nothing in the place of {list} and could not test button clicks and all related to lists after this. How can force this to render list and test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `mount` instead of `shallow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering, I'd like to mention few issues along with improvements to the code which don't necessarily contribute to the failing tests but correcting them might make the tests pass.

1. Logic improvement in `state`.

This is purely preference based but in this case the ternary operator can be shortened down to simple `||` which is easier to read and write as well.

```js
this.state = {
  sheetNames: this.props.sheetNames || [],
  sheetColumnDimensions: this.props.sheetColumnDimensions || {},
};
```

2. Missing `handleOnChange` event handler.

```html
<select id="columnForFilter" onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)}>
  {list}
</select>
```

You are invoking an event handler inside the `<select>` which is missing in the code posted above and the tests might not have thrown any errors.

One more small improvement can be made here. Instead of `onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)}`, simply `onChange={this.handleOnChange}` will also do the job.

3. Syntax Error: Missing `'}'` at the end.

The closing brace of class is missing. Tests throws an error regarding the same.

**Answer**

I tried to reproduce the issue locally with the code you provided (with syntax error corrected). Apart from the syntax error, I could not find any errors and as attached below, the snapshot does contain the `{list}`, i.e., `<option> .. </option>`.

```
exports[`FilterDetails component test suite should render initial layout of FilterDetails.jsx  1`] = `
Array [
  <div>
    <div
      id="fieldForFiltering"
    >
      <select
        id="columnForFilter"
        onChange={[Function]}
      >
        <React.Fragment>
          <option
            value="Sales"
          >
            Sales
          </option>
          <option
            value="Profit"
          >
            Profit
          </option>
        </React.Fragment>
        <React.Fragment>
          <option
            value="Status"
          >
            Status
          </option>
          <option
            value="Quantity"
          >
            Quantity
          </option>
        </React.Fragment>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>,
]
`;
```

Few things you can try are as follows:

1. Make the aforementioned improvements and try if snapshot is being generated properly.
2. The snapshot maybe outdated. When you make any changes and re-run the tests, by default, the snapshot will not be updated. To update snapshot on every change, update the test script in your `package.json`.

**Create React App**

```json
scripts: {
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --updateSnapshot"
}
```

**Jest**

```json
scripts: {
  "test": "jest --updateSnapshot"
}
```

3. If nothing above works, try removing and reinstalling `node_modules`.